# Can I redistribute Microsoft System CLR Types for Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Tags: report, licensing, reportviewer, viewer

Our application uses Report Viewer 2012 runtime for reporting and we want to bundle the runtime in our installer. This component is available for download as a *redistributable* package and therefore I assume that it is ok to package this runtime in our installer and redistribute it.

However, Report Viewer 2012 has a dependency on Microsoft System CLR Types for Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and I cannot find anywhere whether I can redistribute this package with our installer or not?

Can someone guide me on redistribution requirements for this package? Thanks.

**Download links:**

Report Viewer 2012 Runtime: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747

Microsoft System CLR Types for Microsoft SQL Server 2012: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out that this component is redistributable by going over the license agreement that you have to accept during install.